# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent: (?) in Angular 7 and webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular7

I am working in angular 7. I am getting an error while compiling. I have checked the circular dependancy, Injectable() decorator. There is no unused dependancy. I have used @Injectable() in my service. For your information, i am using mac. I can't find any solution.

My code is given bellow:

auth.service.ts

```js
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { HttpService } from '../common/modules/http-with-injector/http.service';
    import { UserData } from '../common/modules/auth/auth.module';
    import { dcrypt } from '../common/_classes/functions';

    @Injectable()
    export class AuthService {
      user: any;
      constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpService,
      ) {}
    }
```

component.ts

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ScriptLoaderService } from 'src/app/common/script-loader.service';
import { AlertService } from 'src/app/common/modules/alert/alert.service';
import { Helpers } from 'src/app/common/helpers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };
  loading = false;
  @ViewChild('hasAlert', { static: true }) alertContainer: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private _script: ScriptLoaderService,
    private router: Router,
    private alert: AlertService,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {
    this.getSettings();
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Try changing `@Injectable()` to `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`.

Comment: I have tried. but not working.

Comment: Please try relative paths in import statements in your LoginComponent instead of absolute paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error may cause of Metadata issue:

> TypeScript includes experimental support for emitting certain types of
>   metadata for declarations that have decorators.

To enable this experimental support, you must set the emitDecoratorMetadata compiler option either on the command line or in your tsconfig.json:

Command Line:

```
tsc --target ES5 --experimentalDecorators --emitDecoratorMetadata
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    }
 }
```

- For more information you may see this:
  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem solved. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added AuthService in NgModule?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [
  AuthService //Your service
  ]
})
```

As mentioned by Richards, you can inject service using below code as well.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```

Comment: I have tried also. It did not work.

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [AuthService]
})